# Android set view flags for AppCompat activity with XML

Tags: android, xml, appcompatactivity

I have the following activity in my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity
        android:name=".gameContent.GameActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

The problem is that I get the exception when I run my project:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

What is the proper XML to set the fullscreen theme for this type of activity?

Comment: On a side note `@android:` resources are inherent to OS version - that's why there's an AppCompat library that defines them when they are not accessible (e.g. not starting with `@android:`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this in your styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.Fullscreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

And then in your manifest

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: It does not recognize `"Theme.AppCompat...."`

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: If it doesn't recognize "Theme.AppCompat...", so you need to add Google support library in your build.gradle.
 `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'`